# How to handle gestures without blocking touches of the lower views in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, swipe, gesture

My task is to handle the swipe left / swipe right gestures which should not block the touching of the views under that.

I used that approach, but it blocks any touching to the lower views:

```
Box {
            // Lower layout
            Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                // doSomething()
            }) {
                ...
            }
            // Swipe Area
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectHorizontalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                            when {
                                dragAmount >= MIN_DRAG_AMOUNT -> onExpand()
                                dragAmount < -MIN_DRAG_AMOUNT -> onCollapse()
                            }
                        }
                    },
            )
        }
```

I also tried pointerInteropFilter, but it didn't help as well

```
pointerInteropFilter {
  ...
  false
}
```

Is there any way in compose to handle swiping without blocking the lower views touching?